# One MySQL user from 2 hosts not on same subnet

Tags: mysql, permissions

I've googled around for this with no luck. I have a master database with one slave. The perms for the slave are set and it runs fine. I'd like to add another slave using a clone of the original server. So far, everything is fine except my slave user is only granted access from one host: 10.10.10.10 . The second slave I'd like to bring up has the IP address 10.10.10.20 and I can't allow access across the entire subnet ( I also can't change the internal IP addresses).

So, I'd like to update the hosts the slaves can access the master to both IP addresses and can seem to figure out how.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the `mysql:user` table  The `user` is likely enabled only from one `host` (by name or IP).  You can do one of two things:

- Add a second occurrence of the user with access from the second host. (Most secure.)
- Change the host criteria to be less restrictive. (Less secure.)

See the [MySQL Access Restrictions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connection-access.html) documentation for possible less restrictive host specifications.

Comment: Thanks @BillThor. That access restrictions doc was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Normally MySQL refer host name instead IP address.

Making a new user called "chaminda" at `mysql:user` using the MySQL shell:

```
CREATE USER 'chaminda'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

The first thing to do is to provide the user with necessary permission and here I have given all permission to the particular user.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'chaminda'@'%';
```

Reload all the privileges.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**Note:** *Here host Name = % and that means you can access this database server from any host. Giving all privileges to the user is a big risk and that's not a best practice. Further If you already create a user set the necessary permission*

If you need retrieve more details use following command

```
select * from  mysql.user \G;
```

***Result***

```
          User: chaminda
          Password: *4E018IOIPOP89896GFYUIUI25B585CF9F
          Select_priv: Y
          Insert_priv: Y
          Update_priv: Y
          Delete_priv: Y
          Create_priv: Y
            Drop_priv: Y
          Reload_priv: Y
        Shutdown_priv: Y
         Process_priv: Y
            File_priv: Y
           Grant_priv: Y
      References_priv: Y
           Index_priv: Y
           Alter_priv: Y
         Show_db_priv: Y
           Super_priv: Y
Create_tmp_table_priv: Y
     Lock_tables_priv: Y
         Execute_priv: Y
      Repl_slave_priv: Y
     Repl_client_priv: Y
     Create_view_priv: Y
       Show_view_priv: Y
  Create_routine_priv: Y
   Alter_routine_priv: Y
     Create_user_priv: Y
           Event_priv: Y
         Trigger_priv: Y
             ssl_type:
           ssl_cipher:
          x509_issuer:
         x509_subject:
        max_questions: 0
          max_updates: 0
      max_connections: 0
 max_user_connections: 0

8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```